# ipfs.add() returns Object [AsyncGenerator] {}

Tags: ipfs

**I am unable to figure out what mistake i have done in the code**

Whenever i am calling api, **ipfs.add('hello')** returns **[object AsyncGenerator]**

> [https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/[object](https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/%5Bobject) AsyncGenerator]

```
  const addFile = async () => {
            const Added = await ipfs.add('hello');
            return Added;
        }
        const fileHash = await addFile();
        return fileHash;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the result of .add() like so:

```
for await (const item of Added) {
  console.log('item', item)
}
```

> item {   path: 'QmWfVY9y3xjsixTgbd9AorQxH7VtMpzfx2HaWtsoUYecaX',
> cid: CID(QmWfVY9y3xjsixTgbd9AorQxH7VtMpzfx2HaWtsoUYecaX),   size: 13 }

Comment: how to create folder  in ipfs and upload image?

Comment: Hi Ishwar, you can learn how to create a folder and upload images in this guide: https://proto.school/#/mutable-file-system

Comment: i gone through the url you shared above , i used those commands from command line and wroks fine, but when i am trying to implement same thing in node.js i am getter’s some error, will you help me out with some source code in nodejs for creating folder and uploading images in ipfs

Comment: @IshwarChandra yes, but please file new question - is very different than original one.